# How to organize category tree?

Tags: category, category-tree

My store sells just one type of product (e.g. Computers). What's the best way to organize the category tree?

**Should I include the main topic in order to permit my customers to browse all my products in 1 single page?**

- **Computers --> Asus --> Intel**

or simply:

- **Asus --> Intel**

?

Answer (score 0):

It would be recommended that the products have the complete path:

> root category - category - subcategory - subcategory of subcategory
> (if exist)

This thing also helps on the SEO side. For example, if a customer accesses the 'Computers' category, he should automatically see all 'Computers' products, whatever their model. You can use the brand (example Asus) as a filter but also as a subcategory. Filter to be displayed in the main category (Computers).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, e.g. what about Homepage? What should I put on it? Furthermore, since I just have one main category (Computers), what should I put in the top navigation menu? Just the Computers category?

Answer (score 0):

Computers --> Asus --> Intel this will be best but you have only one main category that is Computers then use this Asus --> Intel because you can add the Computers category anytime and then shift to other categories into it which is an easy process. Need reindex not more than that but yes it might impact on SEO if not properly handle

Thanks

**EDIT**

Ok, let go easy. What confusion you have is two use "Computers --> Asus --> Intel" or "Asus --> Intel" right, Ok then if you have one type of product "Computers" then you can go for "Asus --> Intel". For example like "ASUS", there is more like "HP", "Dell" than as per luma theme navigation you will get "ASUS", "HP", "DELL" as Navbar element right. If You Do not want Nav in this way then "Computers --> Asus --> Intel" is working fine, But if you want Navbar elements as "ALL", "ASUS", "HP", "DELL" then you have to create ALL subcategory under root category like "ASUS". And assign products with Both "All" and "ASUS" category

In Short, what @Bogdan Pisica says is correct and what I answer is based on your question.

Hope this answer your question

Comment: I'm building it from scratch. So, what's the best option?

Comment: Then use Asus --> Intel because you have mention that you have only computers as main category

Comment: Thanks but the @Bogdan Pisica answer says the opposite. Furthermore, Luma theme doesn't have a "All products" category but I have to say that Luma categories are pretty different. I'm more confused than before.

Comment: @KaMZaTa - Please check the post content edit part.

Comment: So, talking about SEO, there's no difference between set "Computers --> Asus --> Intel" or "Asus --> Intel" and set the second "ALL" subcategory to the products as long as you have the Canonical URL set, right? Or does the first perform a little better than the second one? Furthermore, my concern is that adding a second category to the products could complicate the management and could lead to some errors (e.g. think to which category could grab the Rich Snippet extension I have installed).

Comment: SEO will not be affected by both is up to you or the SEO person who is doing SEO.